# Is that var exist or something?

Tags: python, selenium

I have one very big problem with my variables. I'am new into Programing, and i started with Selenium in python to make small python-facebook-sharing bot. That bot must sharing a post to some groups that I in.
I created a var in loop that checking if variable exist but loop doesn't work. I tried with 'if var in locals():' but still i don't know how can i do it. Please for help L:
here is my code

````
while i <= 100:
    time.sleep(1)
    clicker = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_for_example')
    if clicker in locals():
        clicker.click()
    else:
        continue
    i += 1
driver.close()```
````

Comment: What is `locals()`?

Comment: Check if var exist in local syntax

Comment: @Prophet - `locals` is [locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath` will return web element if it was found or will throw an exception if it wasn't, the `if` doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your if to this

```
if clicker:
```

find_element_by_xpath will return an empty list if not match, so it will go to else